# woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists calls on refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used this hook as below

```php
function registration_errors()
{
    error_log('calls again');
    WC()->session->set('registration_error_message', 'An account is already registered with your email address. Please log in.');
    return home_url();
}

add_filter('woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', 'registration_errors');
```

It seems this hook is calling on page refreshes, not just one time. Every time I refresh the page, it will log the `calls_again` into the `debug.log` file.

How i can prevent firing action after page refreshes and just fires when user entered and existing email in registration form.